# R - Fixing plot legend and other plot characteristics for multiple line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to make a plot with five separate lines that represent different variables (i.e., columns). I've been trying to fix the legend and I can't get it right. The colors also seem to be incorrect, so I'm confused as to how to proceed. Data, code, and current plot are below:

```
test.dat <- data.frame(matrix(c(0,.072,.063,.062,.059,.055,1,.029,.035,.024,.036,.017),
nrow=2,byrow=T))
colnames(test.dat) <- c("X1","Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4","Y5")

test.plot <- ggplot(data=test.dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x=X1, y=Y1, color="darkred")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=X1, y=Y2, color="darkgreen")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=X1, y=Y3, color="darkblue")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=X1, y=Y4, color="darkorange")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=X1, y=Y5, color="darkgoldenrod"))
```

[image]

I'm trying to make the variable names (i.e., Y1, Y2, etc.) the names for the lines on the legend as well as name the legend itself. I've googled around to figure out how to change the legend, but nothing I've tried changes the plot. I also need to fix the the axis labels and add a plot title.

I'm fairly new to ggplot, so a point in the right direction would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier if you change your data from wide to long, and then plot the lines. You are also defining the colors within the aes() parameter which does not change the color, but, in effect, creates a variable with that value.
You did not mention exactly what you want to do with your axis labels, but they can be edited using scale_x_continuous or scale_y_continuous

```
library(tidyverse)

test.dat <- data.frame(matrix(c(0,.072,.063,.062,.059,.055,1,.029,.035,.024,.036,.017),
                              nrow=2,byrow=T))
colnames(test.dat) <- c("X1","Y1","Y2","Y3","Y4","Y5")

test.dat %>%
    gather(Y_var, value, -X1) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = X1, y = value, color = Y_var)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_color_manual(
        values = c("darkred","darkgreen","darkblue","darkorange",
                   "darkgoldenrod")
    ) + 
    labs(title = "Some plot title",
         color = "Some legend title")
```

[image]

Comment: This works. Thank you. Changing to wide format certainly makes the code more intuitive.

Comment: A comment on nomenclature: the OPs original `test.dat` is in "wide format". The code in this answer reshapes it to "long format" using `gather()`.